# Can't package Service Fabric application in Linux environment

Tags: linux, azure, msbuild, azure-service-fabric

I need to package my Service Fabric application in order to deploy it to the Azure Service Fabric cluster.

There is no any error when I use this command in Windows:

`dotnet msbuild SfTestApp/SfTestApp.sfproj /t:Package`

But when I push my source code to Bitbucket and try to package my application at pipeline - I always get the same error message:

```
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.4/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets(396,5): error MSB4018: The "GetPackageRootFiles" task failed unexpectedly. [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/SfTestApp/SfTestApp.sfproj]
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.4/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets(396,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/SfTestApp/ApplicationPackageRoot\'. [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/SfTestApp/SfTestApp.sfproj]
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.4/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets(396,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.UnixFileSystem.FileSystemEnumerable`1.Enumerate() [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/SfTestApp/SfTestApp.sfproj]
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.4/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets(396,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.UnixFileSystem.FileSystemEnumerable`1..ctor(String userPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchTarget searchTarget, Func`3 translateResult) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/SfTestApp/SfTestApp.sfproj]
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.4/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets(396,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.UnixFileSystem.EnumeratePaths(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchTarget searchTarget) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/SfTestApp/SfTestApp.sfproj]
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.4/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets(396,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.Directory.InternalGetFileDirectoryNames(String path, String userPathOriginal, String searchPattern, Boolean includeFiles, Boolean includeDirs, SearchOption searchOption) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/SfTestApp/SfTestApp.sfproj]
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.4/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets(396,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/SfTestApp/SfTestApp.sfproj]
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.4/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets(396,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.BuildTasks.GetPackageRootFiles.FindPackageRootFilesInFileSystem(String fullPackageRootPath) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/SfTestApp/SfTestApp.sfproj]
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.4/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets(396,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.BuildTasks.GetPackageRootFiles.Execute() [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/SfTestApp/SfTestApp.sfproj]
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.4/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets(396,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() in E:\A\_work\17\s\src\Build\BackEnd\TaskExecutionHost\TaskExecutionHost.cs:line 631 [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/SfTestApp/SfTestApp.sfproj]
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.4/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets(396,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__25.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\17\s\src\Build\BackEnd\Components\RequestBuilder\TaskBuilder.cs:line 787 [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/SfTestApp/SfTestApp.sfproj]
```

I've already tried to create empty Service Fabric application (without any service inside) but the error remains.

What is wrong with **GetPackageRootFiles** (as I see from error message)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug in MSBuild...

> Looks like a bug in our MSBuild task that we will fix where it had some platform specific code. FWIW, we haven't tested the VS tooling / MSBuild tasks on Linux yet so you are working in a bit of uncharted territory.

https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/844

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in MsBuild 1.6.5